# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to override the Back button?

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile, worklight-runtime

I have developed a Worklight application Using Dojo 1.9. In my application for returning to previous view i am using a back button in my app's header.

Back Button Code

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
                data-dojo-props="label:'View2 Details',back:'View1', moveTo:'view1'" style="background-color: maroon">
                </div>
```

Is it possible to use the device's back button to navigate to previous view? so that I can use both approaches in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternate solutions:

1. The simplest would be to rely on Dojo Mobile's "bookmarkable"
   feature. For details, see
   https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mobile/bookmarkable.html.
   Live example:
   http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.0/dojo-release-1.9.0/dojox/mobile/tests/test_bk_force-list.html. After transitioning from the home page, pressing browser's back
   button on desktop browsers, or the back button of Android devices,
   triggers a transition back to the initial view.
2. The saner solution for a relatively complex app requiring navigation
   history management would be to build your app using dojox/app. See the documentation at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/app.html and the tutorials at https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojox_app/.

Comment: thanks for the reply.I use bookmarkable feature and its working,but how to exit application when its in the index page,i mean if i press back button from index page i want my application to exit.Is it possible.

Comment: Using this "bookmarkable" how can i reset bookmark stack when reached a particular page/view. Is this possible in dojo.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the concept of "pages" in Dojo, however:

Yes, there is [WL.App.overrideBackButton](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_app_overridebackbutton.html), that you can use to override the default Android Back button functionality (quitting the app) and instead call a callback that will load a different view.

Note that in order to restore the "quit" functionality when the app is in the index page, you will need to use [WL.App.resetBackButton](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_app_overridebackbutton.html) so that the user will be able to quit the app like how s/he is used to in Android.

As for how to handle a multi-page navigation with history, please see the relevant topic [in this training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf). You will have to adjust the code to that you use in Dojo.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have added WL.App.overrideBackButton(backFunc); in wlCommonInit() function and i have also added the function backFunc(), but how should i handle the event in my case. How come i know that from which page back button in pressed.In my project i have 3 back button in 3 different views.

Comment: You need to handle the history of your user's actions and bubble up as s/he presses the Back button.

Comment: See the section titled "implementing multi-page navigation with history" here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf